# Does listOfLists contain at least one list that has one or more items?

Tags: linq

How do I write this linq query:

```
       List<List<string>> listOfLists = new List<List<string>>();

       listOfLists.Add(new List<string>(){"Item1", "Item2"});

       listOfLists.Add(new List<string>() { "Item2", "Item2" });


       //Does listOfLists contain at least one list that has one or more items?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to find if *any* list has *any* items. Two ways of doing that:

- As described, using [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) at both levels (once with a predicate and once without):

  ```
  var any = listOfLists.Any(list => list.Any());
  ```
- Just flatten it and see if there are any items at all, as if there is at least one item, it must belong to a list with at least one item:

  ```
  var any = listOfLists.SelectMany(list => list).Any();
  ```